# Matlab: Neural Network time series import data

Tags: excel, matlab, date, neural-network, time-series

I am quite new to Matlab and need this for a university project. 
I have a excel list containing the following data about the housing price market in one city:
Date, citicens, price

I want to build a neural network and use time series analysation.

But I cannot import the data, because of the Date.

1) Do you know how I can timestamp my data to work with it?

I also have the data for other cities. 
2) Is there a possibility to train the network with the data from the other cities too?

Kind regards

Comment: I would suggest using some form of multi-variable regression, maybe a logistic, rather than jump into neural networks. You can train the regression/NN with any data you want, it does not discriminate. A potentially interesting question would be if you would find different result in different cities. As to the importing the data, I am sorry I am not sure.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. 
I cannot use another algorithm, because I am supposed to use NN